# How can i send key : value to kafka with kafkaconsoleproducer without it beind encoded to json?

Tags: json, apache-kafka

I'm sending a message to kafka manually using kafka-console-producer where key and value are jsons. When it arrives it seems to be encoded to json again and i don't know how to construct the message to be encoded to json i want to send or how to configure either the producer I'm using or the kafka broker itself not to encode messages.

Here is example:

- I have file message.json:

```
{"distributionID": "TB-AARTool-30","senderID": "TB-AARTool","dateTimeSent": 1635405698193,"dateTimeExpires": 1635405698193,"distributionStatus": "System","distributionKind": "Request"};{"TrialId": 3,"TrialSessionId": 5,"TrialStageId": 4}
```

- I'm sending it using command:

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topic --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=;" < /message.json
```

- and when it arrives it looks like:

```
 {
    "topic": "topic",
    "key": "{\"distributionID\": \"TB-AARTool-30\",\"senderID\": \"TB-AARTool\",\"dateTimeSent\": 1635405698193,\"dateTimeExpires\": 1635405698193,\"distributionStatus\": \"System\",\"distributionKind\": \"Request\"}",
    "value": "{\"TrialId\": 3,\"TrialSessionId\": 5,\"TrialStageId\": 4}",
    "partition": 0,
    "offset": 1
  }
```

First of all at the beginning and end of the key and value quotation marks (") were added. Second, all quotation marks (") already in the message were replaced with backslash quotation mark (\"). I just want key and value to be received by kafka as valid jsons.

I'm using:

- confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest docker image which i presume is latest stable kafka server version.
- kafka_2.12-3.0.0 from which I'm using bin/kafka-console-producer.sh (https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/3.0.0/kafka_2.12-3.0.0.tgz) which also contains kafka server and zookeepr but i don't use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data produced fine. Try using `kafka-console-consumer` instead that will not show escaped JSON strings.

---

Regarding the shown output, appears as if you are consuming your record from some REST API or other non-Kafka built-in tool? In that case, yes, your key and value are escaped strings because that is what was produced - strings, not JSON **objects**.

Therefore, you aren't able to get data like this without customizing whatever deserializer gets this output

```
{
    "topic": "topic",
    "key": {
       "distributionID": ...
        ...
    }
    "value": { 
        "TrialId":  ...
        ...   
    } 
    ...
}
```

This isn't a problem for other consumers that are configured to use `StringDeserializer` as you can pass those strings into a JSON parser to get objects

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Unfortunately this doesn't help me. I was hoping i could send message like that without implementing it in my own code or changing the code which read's it from kafka which i have to test (since i haven't wrote it). Maybe you know some other tool which would let me send json object as key and value. Thank you for your time nonetheless.

Comment: As answered, your data is sent fine. `kafka-console-producer` doesn't accept anything except for strings. Doesn't matter how data is encoded. Perhaps you should try `kafka-json-schema-console-producer` or `kafka-avro-console-producer` from Confluent Platform to send **structured data**

Comment: Ok. I didn't understand the answare. Thanks agian. You were really helpfull.

Comment: Well, I didn't understand what "when it arrives it looks like" means. You didn't show your consumer code or mention what tool shows this data

Comment: I'm viewing it in UI of landoop/kafka-topics-ui:latest image (https://hub.docker.com/r/landoop/kafka-topics-ui). But overall i need the message to be in json so this tool (https://github.com/DRIVER-EU/ost) can read it from kafka and change something accordingly. It's supposed to come out of some other tools in the project but i couldn't configure any of them, so i chosen to try a shortcut and send the message manually.

Comment: Your messages are JSON. The UI tool just happens to only know how to deserialize strings, unless (last I checked) you configure it with the Confluent Schema Registry and produce Avro into the topic. Also, that landoop tool hasn't been updated in years. There are better options like AKHQ